# Why did Judah resist Jeremiah as a prophet but accept the reformations led by Josiah?

Tags: jeremiah, josiah, morality

Why did Kingdom of Judah resist Jeremiah as a prophet for 40 year but accept the reformation led by Josiah? Why does God acknowledge his reign as godly though the people eventually were led into captivity based on their objections to the law itself?

Comment: We need a text of scripture on which to focus on this site. Biblical topics are not debated and discussed here. Please see the Tour.

Comment: I agree with  NigelJ - to prevent this question being closed we need some Bible references to analyse.

Comment: Josiah destroyed the high places. It is nowhere implied that the people liked it.